# Assign dynamic function name to ng-click directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I have a dynamic menu loaded inside a AngularJS Controller and I show it in html using ng-repeat, all right until here.

But in just one case (yet), instead of append a url to the "A" tag's href attribute, I have to append a angular method to be called by ng-click.

The problem is, Angularjs doesn't render this ng-click or it's argument

there's an angular way, typing saving, codeless solution for it?

Html:

```
// trying to do it injecting ng-click as a tag attribute
<a ng-repeat="menu in mainMenuList" href="{{menu.href}}" {{menu.params}} >{{menu.name}}</a>

// trying to do it injecting function name inside ng-click
<a ng-repeat="menu in mainMenuList" href="{{menu.href}}" ng-click="{{menu.ngclick}}" >{{menu.name}}</a>
```

Json:

```
$scope.mainMenuList = [
    // normal link with href and no ngclick nor parameter
    { "name" : "Store"  , "href" : "#\/store" },

    // trying to do it injecting ng-click as a tag attribute
    { "name" : "Logoff" , "href" : "" , "params" : " ng-click=\"logoff()\" " },

    // trying to do it injecting just function name to ngclick attribute
    { "name" : "Test"   , "href" : "" , "ngclick" : "userLogoff()" },
];
```

Comment: `ng-click` is angular aware.  It accepts an angular expression, so remove the double curlies.

Comment: `$scope.mainMenuList = [
       { "name" : "Test"   , "href" : "" , "ngclick" : "userLogoff" },
];`
`<button ng-click="this[menu.ngclick]()">{{ title }}</button>`

Comment: @Sawyer's solution works perfectly.